# How can I solve more than 10 Views in a CustomForEach in SwiftUI?

Tags: swift, swiftui

I am working on a **CustomForEach** which try's to act as a `ForEach` like apple offer us, it is working more or less but it face with 2 big issues, first of all, I do not know how can I generate views if the count of views goes more than 10 I do not want also I cannot hard code for every possible count, I am trying to find a way to make it automatic, the second issue is not about this question but I am saying just for pointing the issue, it loads the already loaded Views. But in this question I am trying solve the issue of more than 10 views, to make me free of hard coding.

```
struct ContentView: View {

    @State private var upperBound: Int = Int()

    var body: some View {

        HStack {

            CustomForEachView(range: 0...upperBound) { item in

                TextView(string: item.description)

                Circle().fill(Color.red).frame(width: 5, height: 5, alignment: .center)

            }
            
        }

        Button("add to range") { upperBound += 1 }

    }

}
```

---

```
struct TextView: View {

    let string: String

    var body: some View {
 
        print("rendering " + string)

        return Text(string)
 
    }
 
}
```

---

```
struct CustomForEachView<Content: View>: View {

    let range: ClosedRange<Int>
    let content: (Int) -> Content

    init(range: ClosedRange<Int>, @ViewBuilder content: @escaping (Int) -> Content) {
        
        self.range = range
        self.content = content
        
    }

    var body: some View {
        
        let rangeCount1 = content(range.lowerBound)
        let rangeCount2 = Group { rangeCount1; content(range.lowerBound + 1) }
        let rangeCount3 = Group { rangeCount2; content(range.lowerBound + 2) }
        let rangeCount4 = Group { rangeCount3; content(range.lowerBound + 3) }
        let rangeCount5 = Group { rangeCount4; content(range.lowerBound + 4) }
        let rangeCount6 = Group { rangeCount5; content(range.lowerBound + 5) }
        let rangeCount7 = Group { rangeCount6; content(range.lowerBound + 6) }
        let rangeCount8 = Group { rangeCount7; content(range.lowerBound + 7) }
        let rangeCount9 = Group { rangeCount8; content(range.lowerBound + 8) }
        let rangeCount10 = Group { rangeCount9; content(range.lowerBound + 9) }

        return Group {
            
            if      range.count == 1 { rangeCount1 }
            else if range.count == 2 { rangeCount2 }
            else if range.count == 3 { rangeCount3 }
            else if range.count == 4 { rangeCount4 }
            else if range.count == 5 { rangeCount5 }
            else if range.count == 6 { rangeCount6 }
            else if range.count == 7 { rangeCount7 }
            else if range.count == 8 { rangeCount8 }
            else if range.count == 9 { rangeCount9 }
            else if range.count == 10 { rangeCount10 }
            else { Text("Need to work!") }
            
        }
 
    }
 
}
```

Comment: What are you actually trying to accomplish by building a custom `ForEach`?

Comment: For learning and more power on Views. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This approach seems to accomplish what you want:

```swift
struct CustomForEachView<Content: View>: View {

    let range: ClosedRange<Int>
    let content: (Int) -> Content

    init(range: ClosedRange<Int>, @ViewBuilder content: @escaping (Int) -> Content) {
        
        self.range = range
        self.content = content
        
    }
    
    private func tail(of range: ClosedRange<Int>) -> ClosedRange<Int>? {
        return range.count > 1 ? (range.lowerBound + 1)...range.upperBound : nil
    }
    
    var body: some View
    {
        content(range.lowerBound)
        if let tailRange = tail(of: range) {
            CustomForEachView(range: tailRange, content: content)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Very Nice and clean! I do not know how you could solve the issue! thanks

Comment: I'm glad it helps.  It's a simple recursion.  If you find that its performance degrades for large ranges, you could divide the range in half rather than as first element + rest of the range.  That would make it have a binary tree-like structure with a shallower recursion depth.  That said, from what I've gleaned from SwiftUI internals from poking around in the debugger, I don't think it would matter.  The underlying NS/UIHostingView seems to contain the content views directly in it rather than a deep view hierarchy.